# Does warping of space under relativity suggest displacement

Tags: special-relativity, space-expansion

The picture I see in documentaries is a flat piece of cloth depressed downward by the large mass, say a star, and objects falling into the depression. But this is one side of the star.So if I were to look on the other side of the star, there would be another depression going on the opposite side. So, these two depressions should cancel right?

Seems to me in this case the Newtonian concept of gravity being influenced by a point in the centre of the larger object ... seems more intuitive in this scenario

Comment: I proposed a duplicate as it explains why the "rubber sheet" analogy you talk about for gravity is quite wrong.

Answer (score 0):

These pictures are misleading, since the rubber cloth is 2 dimensional it shall provide a picture how curved space works like attraction, but in reality the three dimensional space is curved, but you can not really picture this. The tree dim curvature goes in all three direction, so this picture is wrong.